# Movement towards continuous integration in progress, any suggestions?

Tags: c++, c, continuous-integration, nightly-build

We have a bunch of C/C++ modules and projects for QNX4, QNX6 and Linux. All of these are written in Eclipse/QNX Momentics and we use Project Sets (psf files) to combine different modules into projects as required. The projects are built using make. The psf files specify which modules are required for a certain project.

I have looked at two CI/Nightly build systems (BuildBot, Apache Continuum), but neither works particularly well with psf files, or supports them directly.

Does any one know of a CI system that would allow me to work with them, without having to use scripts to check stuff out, etc?

Btw, we are using CVS for versioning.

Comment: Check out this similar question that uses the Hudson CI tool to do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502776/best-way-to-automatically-check-out-and-compile-eclipse-projects-with-ant-in-huds

Comment: Thanks! I went through the post. It seems he has made his own plugin, which is something I cannot afford time or resources for. I guess I will ask how/what he did, or if he has been able to find anything better.

Comment: Finally! I used the ant4eclipse plugin and created my own script using their cvsGetProjectSet ant task. Very useful! Their webpage is at http://www.ant4eclipse.org if anyone is interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Hudson along with Ant and ant4eclipse plugin. Ant4Eclipse works with ProjectSet files, so it is perfect. Ant can also do Telnet and so I use it for QNX4

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience (limited) with [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html).  It is very flexible and extensible, and has a number of plugins for third-party tools and version control systems; however it runs of Windows; you did not specify a platform.  Of course you development platform and CI server platform need not be the same however.

Comment: Thanks Clifford. I would prefer it to be on Linux, but if required, Windows will also work.

Comment: CruiseControl does work in linux - their docs mention a "unix" install script, and it's running at my workplace under centos5. (I don't really have anything to do with it though, can't give advice.)